# AngularJS Dynamic menu doesn't work when number of items > 10

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am creating a simple AngularJS page with MVC project that retrieves items from database table and display them as a dynamic menu.

The list works perfectly as long as the number of items less than 10??

When I tried to troubleshoot this issue, I came up with one explanation which is AngularJS doesn't read number as numbers! So the comparison doesn't go properly.

To be more specific, I have the following table:
[image]

The menu should be listed as:

```
Page1 - Page2 - Page3 - Page4 - Page5 - Page6 - Page7 - Page8 - Page9
          |       |
          |       |
          |     Page14
          |     Page15
          |
          |
        Page10 - Page11 - Page12 - Page12
                            |
                            |
                          Page13
```

But I doesn't really display what I am expecting..

- Under **Page1** I have **Page13**
- **Page13** is also listed under **Page2**
  [image]

[image]

The following is my code that get the list and display it:

**The MVC Controller**

```
namespace MVCAngularDynamicMenu.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetSiteMenu()
    {
        using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
        {
            var menu = dc.SiteMenus.ToList();
            return new JsonResult { Data = menu, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
}
}
```

**The JS Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('menuController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.SiteMenu = [];
$http.get('/home/GetSiteMenu').then(function (response) {
    $scope.SiteMenu = response.data;
}, function (error) {
    alert('Error');
})
}])
```

**The View**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="menuController">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="treeMenu">
        <a href="{{menu.Url}}">{{menu.Name}}</a>
        <ul ng-if="(SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}).length > 0">
            <li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <ul class="main-navigation">
        <li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : 0}" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**This is how the returned JSON looks like**

```
[
{"ID":1,"Name":"Page1","Url":"/p1","ParentID":0},
{"ID":2,"Name":"Page2","Url":"/p2","ParentID":0},
{"ID":3,"Name":"Page3","Url":"/p3","ParentID":0},
{"ID":4,"Name":"Page4","Url":"/p4","ParentID":0},
{"ID":5,"Name":"Page5","Url":"/p5","ParentID":0},
{"ID":6,"Name":"Page6","Url":"/p6","ParentID":0},
{"ID":7,"Name":"Page7","Url":"/p7","ParentID":0},
{"ID":8,"Name":"Page8","Url":"/p8","ParentID":0},
{"ID":9,"Name":"Page9","Url":"/p9","ParentID":0},
{"ID":10,"Name":"Page10","Url":"/p10","ParentID":2},
{"ID":11,"Name":"Page11","Url":"/p11","ParentID":2},
{"ID":12,"Name":"Page12","Url":"/p12","ParentID":2},
{"ID":13,"Name":"Page13","Url":"/p13","ParentID":12},
{"ID":14,"Name":"Page14","Url":"/p14","ParentID":3},
{"ID":15,"Name":"Page15","Url":"/p15","ParentID":3}
]
```

Again, I suspect that the issue is in casting the ID and PartnerID fields as string while they are int. But I am not really sure

Comment: What does the JSON from `GetSiteMenu` look like?

Comment: How does the markup display a sub menu for a sub menu? Perhaps Page 13 is listing under Page 12 but it looks like the same vertical drop down. What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: The rendered HTML is on the screenshots I've attached

Comment: I will post the JSON file by editing my post

Comment: This could be an issue with your filter not being strict enough. In your view, try adding strict:

`<li ng-repeat="menu in SiteMenu | filter:{ParentID : menu.ID}:strict" ng-include="'treeMenu'"></li>`

Comment: Thank you. I added strict to the filter but nothing changed